# Whole table row clickable except the button with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple table and I write some JS code in order to achieve that whole `tr` become a `data-href`. Everything works very nice except for one thing.

Now the whole row is clickable and that is fine, but there is a small issue, if you click on the delete button, it takes you to the update page (data-href), and I want to avoid that. So my question is how can I modify that code for the whole row to stay clickable except that delete button?

Here is my code:

```js
$("tr").each(function() {
    const $tr = $(this);
    $tr.attr("data-href", $tr.find("a").attr("href"))
})

$('*[data-href]').on('click', function() {
    window.location = $(this).data("href");
});
```

```css
.modal {
  padding:5px;
  background-color:red;
  color:#fff;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td> Age</td>
      <td>
         <a href="/update/1">Update</a>
         <a data-toggle="modal" class="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Can somebody try to help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use the `is()` method to determine what element within the `tr` was clicked on. If it was an `a` element then you can prevent the `window.location` from being updated.

Also note that you can update the `data-href` of each `tr` using an implicit loop which makes the code slightly more succinct. Try this:

```js
$('tr').attr('data-href', function() {
  return $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});

$('*[data-href]').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is('a')) {
    window.location.assign($(this).data("href"));
  }
});
```

```css
.modal {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>
      <a href="/update/1">Update</a>
      <a data-toggle="modal" class="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for this code. This code works but if I put an icon inside the button, it does not work, here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/subg8p16/5/  When you click on the icon it redirects you

Comment: In that case you need a tweak to the logic so that it excludes the `a` and any child element within it: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/mq12bLgz/